# ± in regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am doing regular expression with python 2.7.

My document has a string `"INL±1LSB"`, and I am trying to find this string and print `1LSB`.

I tried this command:

```
strings = re.findall(r'INL(?:\xb1)(1LSB)', f.read())
print (strings)
```

but it can't find. (the result of print is `[]`).

but when I change the string in the document to `"±1LSB"` and use the commands like:

```
strings = re.findall(r'(?:\xb1)(1LSB)', f.read())
print (strings)
```

the output would be `['1LSB']`

I think the problem is that it can't find any character before ±.

What should I do for fixing that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to [SO]! Your problem might be affected by factors that you haven't included in your question. The easiest way that you can be certain that your readers have enough info is to provide a [mcve]. That is, reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error (I expect that would be about five lines in your case). include the input, the expected and the actual output. [Edit] your question and copy-paste all of that info. (*Never* retype your code.)

Comment: Also, for this specific question, please tell us how the input file is encoded.

Comment: Are you sure that you’re using the right encoding, and that the character you’re looking for really is `\xb1` in that encoding?

Comment: Maybe you are reading file in a wrong way? check encodings..

Comment: In particular, if the file is UTF-8, not Latin-1, what you’d actually have is `\xc2\xb1`, which can be pretty confusing—if you just search for `\xb1` you find it, but if you search for `INL\xb1` you don’t.

Comment: http://regex101.com will help

Comment: @abarnert when I changed to \xc2\xb1, it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your document has the string `INL±1LSB` encoded in UTF-8, but you’re trying to match the same string encoded in Latin-1 (or some close relative). Normally, encoding problems are a lot more obvious than this, but you managed to find a particularly insidious one that’s easy to get confused by.

But first, the solution: either

- Change your regex to use the UTF-8 encoding instead of the Latin-1 encoding, so it matches the search bytes, or
- `decode('utf8')` the bytes and search them with a Unicode rather than bytes regex.

---

Explanation:

In UTF-8, the`±` character is encoded as two bytes, `\xc2\xb1`. In Latin-1, it’s encoded as a single byte, `\xb1`. Which happens to be the same as the second byte of the UTF-8. This happens for only a small block of characters toward the end of Latin-1, most of which aren’t that commonly used, so it’s not a pitfall that most people learn about until they get bitten by it.

If you search the bytes for `\xb1LSB`, it will match, just as it would for Latin-1, by matching half the character. But if you search them for `INL\xb1`, it will fail, which is the problem you were asking about.

The only way you’d be likely to spot the problem is if you went the decode-everything-to-Unicode route (which is often the case; that’s why Python 3 was designed to encourage you to decode everything whenever possible).